# AngularJS undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs

Im trying out a simple http app using Angularjs. 
My code is

```
var studentApp = angular.module('studentApp',['ui.bootstrap']);
studentApp.factory('studentSession', function($http){
    return {
        getSessions: function() {
            return $http.post('/services', { 
                type : 'getSource',
                ID    : 'TP001'
            });
        }
    }
});

studentApp.controller('studentMenu',function($scope, studentSession){
    studentSession.getSessions().success($scope.handleSuccess);
    $scope.handleSuccess = function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    };
});
```

While trying to run above code, i get the error `Undefined is not a function` in chrome . Searching through stackoverflow the recommended fix is to provide scope for function. Error persists even after scoping the function.

Suspected problem with corrupt angular file, Since the code works fine if i move the getSession code inside controller. But the error persists on angular version 1.0.6 and 1.1.4(both uncompressed and minified version).

The error varies in firefox. its `fn is not a function` with uncompressed angularjs and `b is not a function` with minified angularjs.

any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Comment: did u try using anonymous callback function in success

Comment: Wow. that works perfectly. So is it problem with angular or my definition?

Comment: `$scope.handleSuccess` is undefined when you passed it to `.success()`. Just put the handler above the rest of your code in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Oki so based on the comments the following code works

```
var studentApp = angular.module('studentApp',['ui.bootstrap']);
studentApp.factory('studentSession', function($http){
    return {
        getSessions: function() {
            return $http.post('/services', { 
                type : 'getSource',
                ID    : 'TP001'
            });
        }
    }
});

studentApp.controller('studentMenu',function($scope, studentSession){
    //------Code Change---------
    //Moved before function call.
    $scope.handleSuccess = function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    }; 
    studentSession.getSessions().success($scope.handleSuccess);
});
```